# Jaspersoft is returning 200 OK but not response data

Tags: laravel, jasper-reports, laravel-5.3

I am using JasperSoft Studio API call in my laravel application (ajax call) to generate reports. Small reports (say 30000 rows in csv/excel, pdf) is generating properly but large reports are not generating.  Jasper is returning 200 OK status but not returning response data. how to solve this issue?

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: base_url+'admin/get-report-details',
                data:   $('form#jsperReports').serialize(), 
                dataType:'json',
                timeout:1200000, 
                beforeSend: function(){ 
                    $('#reportDetailsRow').addClass('hide');
                    var dialog = bootbox.dialog({
                        message: '<p class="text-center">Please wait while we do something...</p>',
                        closeButton: false
                    });
                },
                success:function(data){ 
                    $('.modal').modal('hide');
                    if(!!data && data.success == true){
                            $('#reportDetails').html(data.html);
                            $('#reportDetailsRow').removeClass('hide');
                    }else if (!!data && data.success == false) {
                        showMsgModel("Error",data.msg)
                    }
                }
            });
```